# group by 2 fields while returning the first value from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that will select two fields, group them and then order the results based on the first result of the second field.  There is a one to many relationship between these two fields.

```
select Product
    , Material
from dbo.Files
group by Product, Material
ORDER BY Product, MIN(Material)
```

The result is exactly what we want. In reality, there are actually dozens of "10-001" records but we just get the first one.

```
Product     Material
10          001
10          002
10          003
10          004
10          005
10          006
10          007
10          008
10          009
11          001
11          009
13          012
13          013
13          014
```

The problem is when I want to display additional columns.  Obviously I cannot select additional columns unless I also add them to the group by statement.  But when I add them to my group by statement it changes the results.

This is as close as I have come.

```
select Product
    ,Material
    ,XXIMPORT
    ,Field1
    ,Field2
    ,Field3
    ,Field4
    ,Field5
from dbo.files
where Field1 is not null
group by Product
    ,Material
    ,XXIMPORT
    ,Field1
    ,Field2
    ,Field3
    ,Field4
    ,Field5
ORDER BY Product
    , MIN(Material)
    , MIN(Field1)
    , MIN(Field2)
```

With these results:

```
Product     Material    XXIMPORT    Field1          Field2
10          NULL        NULL        OUTER DIAMETER  CRITICAL FIT
10          001         5/27/15     Inside Diameter Cross Section
10          001         5/27/15     Part            INSIDE DIAMETER
10          002         5/27/15     OUTER DIAMETER  INSIDE DIAMETER
10          003         5/27/15     ID              OD
10          003         5/27/15     TYPE (TY)       Thickness (T)
10          011         5/27/15     OVERALL LENGTH  THREAD SIZE
10          012         5/27/15     Height (HT)     Outer Diameter (OD)
```

So I know *why* the results are changing... but how can I tell SQL Serve to just return the first result it finds in the matching "other" columns? For example, just the top "10-001" row or the top "10-003" row.

Everything depends on the result of the first query. Based on other posts on stackoverflow that look very similar, I have tried to put the first part in a sub query with typical results. I have also tried to join the table on itself and add the columns but I must not have the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function here to sort your rows in the order you desire, based on Product and Material.

```
WITH cteFiles AS (
    SELECT Product
          ,Material
          ,XXIMPORT
          ,Field1
          ,Field2
          ,Field3
          ,Field4
          ,Field5
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product, Material ORDER BY Field1, Field2) AS RowNum
        FROM dbo.Files
)
SELECT *
    FROM cteFiles
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `ORDER BY ... MIN()` makes no sense. `Material` is used in your grouping term, so there is only 1 possible value in each group, and MIN is redundant.

As for your question, there is logically no definition of "first" or any other order related feature unless you explicitly specify one (such as using `ORDER BY`).

You need to explicitly tell SQL what you want it to do.

If you really don't care which values you get in the non-grouping columns than:

```
1. you probably shouldn't include them in the result set anyway.
2. You could use one of:
  2.1. Correlated Subquery with TOP 1
  2.2. CROSS APPLY
  2.3. PARTITION BY
  2....
```